How to Send data between activities and data should NOT be persisted after being trransferred?
If You are developing an android application and need to securely transfer a user's username from login activity to userprofile activity. the username must not persist in memory after being transferred.
Should I use Intent and bundle the username inta a key-value pair through intent.putExtra("username", "my_value")
or Use a shared ViewModel to temporarily store the data and access it in UserProfileActivity
or Implement a custom Parcelable class for the username and pass it throguh an Intent
or save username to a SharedPrefernces and access it in UserProfileActivity

The best solution is to not have two activities here. Modern Android app development uses few activities, with fragments or composables for individual screens. That makes it easier to pass data more conventionally, using simple method calls in many cases. The only one of your cited solutions that meets your criteria is "Use a shared ViewModel to temporarily store the data and access it in UserProfileActivity", and sharing viewmodels between activities is a challenge IIRC.

it is a question in online assesment for android job position, so I will follow your answer about creating a temporary shared view model"
